# Ubuntu and NVIDIA drivers issues

Tags: nvidia, freeze

I can't use NVIDIA drivers installed via PPA or from NVIDIA sites.
Everytime I try to boot after installation, I end with black screen with static cursor on top left corner.
But when I choose drivers in section Additional drivers, it boots BUT I can't change to NVIDIA nor Intel via `prime-select` command. It shows something with alternatives not set or something like that.

[Log included](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B2rNGHde_S07TlBmbm5LeW9nS0E&authuser=0)

P.S.: I also had issue about NVIDIA driver, which cause to freeze screen, but sounds and everything else was still working. Temporary solution was CTRL + ALT + F1 then CTRL + ALT + F7 but it happend after few seconds/minutes later. It mostly happens when playing minecraft. Don't you know about anything about it? Is it bug?

Thanks for answer
Laptop Specs:
CPU: Intel i3-2328M 2.2GHz
VGA: NVIDIA 620M
RAM: 4 GB
OS: Ubuntu 14.04 (using Unity or Cinnamon)

Comment: This seems to be exactly to be the same issue as in the thread i just solved with cerr. Try to reinstall nvidia drivers as in link to duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

Try to reinstall your nvidia drivers for your card. For example:

`sudo apt-get install --reinstall nvidia-331`

Comment: Result: Intel - cinnamon running in software render mode, NVIDIA - completely screwed desktop (black wallpaper, no buttons, etc. ...)

Comment: You need to install the NVIDIA drivers for your graphics card. The command I wrote ist just an example. Check the ubuntu [Wiki](http://www.nvidia.de/download/driverResults.aspx/79440/de) page and the [NVIDIA](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BinaryDriverHowto/Nvidia) homepage to find the correct driver for your device.

Comment: Newest WHQL driver is 340.58. I will reinstall Ubuntu tomorrow and try to install it via ppa(?)

Comment: Thats a way to do it, too ;-) I had some luck with installing the drivers by directly downloading them from the NVIDIA homepage when repositories didn't work. You could try this, too if ppa does not work.

Comment: HALLELUYAH. I managed to get it working by installing BETA 346.16 via PPA. Still, what if it freezes? What should I do then? (background sound and everything is working, check P.S.)

Comment: Uh-oh. I think I found the problem. The blackscreen, low resolution and so on was caused by INTEL DRIVERS not Nvidia. I'll try it one more time from scratch.

Comment: So. After reinstalling Ubuntu from scratch, I installed nvidia-346 beta drivers. As I though, Intel was the issue. Still I got those freezing after few seconds-minutes of using nvidia drivers. Any ideas?

Comment: Could you please update the logs (syslog and xorg). Are there still the same error messages ? (Could you please use pastebin or something else for people without google drive).

Comment: http://pastebin.com/P7PE0ULk - xorg and http://pastebin.com/bGkyLXee - syslog. The syslog starts around that freeze (happened two times only)

Comment: Hmpf - nothing supicious. If you have two graphic cards you could check [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HybridGraphics) article. But I think for now its more likely that there is something from with the driver or the environment (kernel). Try to boot ubuntu with different acpi options or without acpi (BE CAREFUL WITH THAT - check link for why) as described [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BootOptions)

Comment: I dont know why, but I played Minecraft (heavily modded :) ) about 2 hours with no freeze. Weird, seems that is working now. I will bookmark those web pages just in case. Thank you really really much @kofrezo

Comment: Thats good news ! You are welcome.